# Excluir todas as linhas que possuam uma string específica

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

Gostaria de excluir todas as linhas que possuírem a string `Excluído`, fazendo a busca à partir de uma string específica até o final de uma outra. Exemplo:

```
<p class="FolderPath">
    <table class="DiffTable">
        <tr>
                <td class="DiffName">
                    <a name="I36676">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Excluído no destino
                </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
</p>
```

Apagaria todas as linhas que possuírem no meio delas a string `Excluído` começando a busca pela string à partir de `<p class="FolderPath">`  até à string `</p>`. Eu sei como apagar a linha contendo a string:

```
sed '/Excluído/d' arquivo.txt
```

> Como seria apagar `N` linhas ? começando de `<p class="FolderPath">`  até a string `</p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando Perl:

```
perl -n0E 'say grep !/Excluído/ , split(/(<p class="FolderPath">.*?<\/p>)/s)'
```

onde:

- `split(/(<p class="FolderPath">.*?<\/p>)/s)` divide o ficheiro de entrada por parágrafos e seus intermédios
- `say grep !/Excluído/` imprime as unidades que não contêm "Excluído"
- `perl -n0E` processar o ficheiro todo de uma só vez

Comment: eu usei o comando assim: `perl -n0E 'say grep !/Excluído/ , split(/(<p class="FolderPath">.*?<\/p>)/s)' arquivo.html` e me retornou o seguinte: /Excluído/: Event not found.

Comment: @Rakiz, estás em linux, certo? Aqui funciona bem. De certeza que incluiste as a`' ...' ` ?

Comment: sim, estou em ubuntu, continua dando o mesmo retorno: /Excluído/: Event not found .

Comment: @Rakiz verifica se escreveste as `'   '` que estão à volta do comando (faz mesmo cut and paste).

Comment: falha minha JJoão eu estava testando seu comando no terminal, não em um script. Agora ele fez certo sem apagar as tags quando se repetem, como eu uso esse comando perl para modificar o arquivo em questão? sem apenas ele me retornar o resultado no terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma solução aqui rápida, depois acrescento uma mais "polida".

```
sed -n '/DiffTable/,/<\/p>/p' arquivo.html |grep -q Excluído && sed '/"DiffTable"/,/<\/p>/{//!d}' arquivo.html || echo "Palavra buscada nao existe"
```

Parâmetros:

**sed -n '/DiffTable/,/</p>/p' arquivo.html |grep -q Excluído &&**

O sed vai extrair todo o conteúdo que estiver entre DiffTable e </p> e com o grep, verificamos se a string Excluído, existe.

**sed '/"DiffTable"/,/</p>/{//!d}' arquivo.html**

Aqui é onde fazemos a substituição, excluindo todas as linhas de DiffTable e </p>. O parâmetro **{//!d}** Mantém as linhas das tags procuradas, se você deseja excluir, troque por apenas **d**

**|| echo "Palavra buscada nao existe"**

Apenas para avisar que a palavra não foi achada no grep

Comment: eu usei o comando `sed -n '/DiffTable/,/<\/p>/p' arquivo.html |grep -q Excluído && sed '/"DiffTable"/,/<\/p>/{//d}' arquivo.html || echo "Palavra buscada nao existe"` sem a exclamação no d , ele me retornou sem o `<table class="DiffTable">` e sem o `</p>` mas não deletou as outras linhas

Comment: Opa, a parte da substituição ficou assim?
  `sed '/"DiffTable"/,/<\/p>/d' arquivo.html` 

Aqui está funcionando como eu entendi que você queria, deletar todas as linhas entre essas tags se existe a palavra Excluído. Me avisa se deu certo,

Comment: ah sim, o problema estava no d , funcionou agora!

Comment: @MrPaper, se tiveres no ficheiro dois paragrafos com tabelas, uma com "Excluído" e outra sem, o teu programa vai apagar as duas! Parece-me que o que é pedido é que só se apague os parágrafos que contêm "excluída".

Comment: Opa, JJoão, verdade.  Se existirem duas tags iguais, uma com a string buscada e outra sem, vai excluir as duas. Se o arquivo dele tiver repetições das tags buscadas, não vai dá certo.

Comment: Fiz o teste com mais de uma tag como o JJoão falou, realmente ele exclui as duas. Como proceder?